# populate combobox dynamically in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, combobox

I add this control how i assign it tag and content dynamically ??

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbTst" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDirection, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Tag" Canvas.Left="82" Canvas.Top="19">
  <ComboBoxItem Content="North" Tag="0"/>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="East" Tag="90"/>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="South" Tag="180"/>
  <ComboBoxItem Content="West" Tag="270"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        ComboBox cbTst = new ComboBox { Height = 30, Width = 100 };
        cbTst.SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedDirection, Mode=TwoWay}";
        cbTst.SelectedValuePath = "Tag";

        cbTst.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "North", Tag = 0 });
        cbTst.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "East", Tag = 90 });
        cbTst.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "South", Tag = 180 });
        cbTst.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "West", Tag = 270 });

        Gridx.Children.Add(cbTst);
```

XAML:

```
   <Grid x:Name="Gridx" Margin="231,162,201,147">
   </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

serversList.Items.??

for example you can add textbox as an item of you combox

```
TextBlock tx = new TextBlock();
tx.Text = "something";
cbTst.Items.Add(tx);"
```

or you can remove an item like this:
    cbTst.Items.RemoveAt(index of the item you want to remove)

Comment: this is just content of combobox , but the problem is how we bind it with both value and content.